# Table-valued parameters for in clause are slower then simple in clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, table-valued-parameters

I have sql queries with some `IN` clauses. In order to improve query plan caching I decided to use table-valued parameters. 
Here is the sample `WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM @P1)`. 
@P1 is variable of the following type :

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Ids] AS TABLE(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
```

But I notice that some queries become slower.
Here is query example :

```
select * from SomeTable s where ((s.SomeForeignId in (select id from @p1)) or s.SomeForeignId is null)
```

which performs in 2.1 sec on my db.

And old query :

```
select * from SomeTable s where ((s.SomeForeignId in (1,2,3.....)) or s.SomeForeignId is null)
```

performs in 1.8 sec.

I notice the difference in query plan. Plan of the first query consists of 2 parts (one for null check, one for in clause) and then comes concatenation. While the second plan is just index seek.

Is there any way I can improve my parameterized query to perform faster?

P.S. This is just the sample distilled query, I want to know if anything is incorrect with this `in (select id from @p1)` part.

Comment: ofcourse ...you are reducing server's time to execute a select statement

Comment: Can you show the table structure of `SomeTable`, including indexes, the number of rows in the table, and how many values you're passing in to `@p1`? Also can you clarify how you're getting an index seek in the second plan while using `SELECT *` - can you post the actual execution plans somewhere?

Comment: This is just the sample query. Table contains near 1 mln records, @p1 contains about 20 records, query result is about 50 000 records. I want to make sure that such use "in (select id from @p1)" is correct way to parameterize in clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

1. [Don't use `SELECT *` - just list the columns you actually need](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list).
2. [Use the schema prefix always](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).
3. Use `EXISTS` rather than `IN` (since the former can short circuit):

   ```
   SELECT cols FROM dbo.SomeTable AS s 
     WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @p1 WHERE ID = s.SomeForeignId)
     OR SomeForeignId IS NULL;
   ```
4. The above may still end up with a concatenation (which essentially means a `UNION`), but you may try writing your own `UNION ALL` to avoid the `OR`:

   ```
   SELECT cols FROM dbo.SomeTable AS s 
     WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @p1 WHERE ID = s.SomeForeignId)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT cols FROM dbo.SomeTable
     WHERE SomeForeignId IS NULL;
   ```

What's troubling me is that either of your existing variations take almost two seconds. Please be sure that there is an index on `SomeTable.SomeForeignId` - not just a foreign key constraint, but an actual non-clustered index. It's not clear in your question that this is the index you get a seek on.

Comment: I've posted the sample distilled query. My production query does not use select *, and have index on foreign key which is used in plan. Advice 3 does not help, the time is the same, advice 4 makes time the same as with "in (1,2,3)", which is great. But as my production query is too big and contains partition, i don't want move to union. I just thought maybe there is another faster way to rewrite "s.SomeForeignId in (select id from @p1)" part. (this select part discomforts me, as query plan says it is executed many times). If there will be no other suggestions, I'll mark this as answer, thanks!

Comment: #3 is the one that usually helps me.  In fact, a few of us issued an internal "edict" that there be no IN clauses in production code (unless you could prove it worked better).  Upvote.